# Gatsby-GraphQL - Fetching remote data from a postgres server

Tags: reactjs, postgresql, graphql, gatsby

I have an existing database served on postgres locally.

I'd like to fetch that data via GraphQL in my Gatsby app. I'm using `gatsby-source-pg` to do this.

It's not clear from the [docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-source-pg/) + example [here](https://github.com/graphile/gatsby-source-pg-example) how to set this up properly. From what I understand, you need the two highlighted portions below.

```js
// ./src/components/test.js

import { graphql } from 'gatsby';
    
export const query = graphql` // (1) graphQL query
  {
    postgres {
      allUsers {
        nodes {
          id
          firstLastName
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;

const Test = ({data}) => { // (2) grab the `data` prop (not sure where this comes from)  
  return (
    <AppLayout>
      {data.postgres.allUsers.nodes.map(user => <p>{user.firstLastName}</p>)} // data is undefined
    </AppLayout>
  )
}

export default Test
```

```js
// gatsby-config.js
    {
      resolve: "gatsby-source-pg",
      options: {
        connectionString: "postgres://user@localhost:5432/testdb",
        schema: "public",
      },
    },
```

Questions:

- How do I query data from the `./src/components` directory? The `data` prop returns `undefined` if I run the exact code above. I noticed this same setup *works* when running it from `./src/pages/index.js`. Maybe I'm missing `options` parameter in `gatsby-source-pg` to tell it which directories to look at?
- How is `query` and `data` from the code above connected? I couldn't tell by looking at the example.

Comment: That graphql will automatically run if it is exported from a page component (and the result added as a data prop). Since your `test` component is is in the `./src/components/` folder, it isn't getting run.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use a static query if you want to query in a non-page component.

Comment: @ksav Yes! This is what I was looking for, thank you :)